# How do you print the return type from an ASP.Net page method?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

***Please read the update at the bottom.***

I created a Page Method that sends an email with info from a contact form. The form gets launched in a colorbox window and the form is it's own .aspx page.

I am able to call the page method but it is erroring out and I can't seem to print the actual exception even though I am returning it as a string.

The summary of the Page Method is

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string SendEmail(string name, string email, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            // send the email

            return "success"; 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { 
            return ex.ToString(); 
        }
     }




CLIENT CODE:

<script type="text/javascript">

    // add event handler for submit button
    $addHandler($get('SendEmailPageMethod'), 'click', EmailPageMethod);

    function EmailPageMethod() {
        var name = $get('name').value;
        var email = $get('email').value;
        var message = $get('message').value;

        // call pagemethod sending form data
        PageMethods.SendEmail(name, email, message, SendEmailCallback, ErrorCallback);
    }

    function SendEmailCallback(resultString) {
        alert(resultString);
    }

    function ErrorCallback(error) {
        alert(error.get_message());
    }

</script>
```

It seems that the errorcallback function is getting called every time but error.get_message just tells me that the pagemethod failed.

I tried

```
function SendEmailCallback(resultString) {
        alert(resultString);
    }
```

but it just said [Object object].

I also tried

```
function SendEmailCallback(resultString) {
        alert(String(resultString));
    }
```

but it still says [object Object].

Is there a way that I can print the entire exception to see what going on? I am very new to Page Methods so I am hitting a wall here.

Thanks.

UPDATE - I got this error when I pressed submit.

I got this error:

```
POST 
http://localhost:1427/PortfolioWebsite/ContactForm.aspx/SendEmail 404 (Not Found) (program):5
Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.executeRequest (program):5
Sys.Net._WebRequestManager.executeRequest (program):5
Sys.Net.WebRequest.invoke (program):5
Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke (program):5
Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy._invoke (program):5
PageMethods.SendEmail (program):16
PageMethods.SendEmail (program):34
EmailPageMethod (program):11
b
```

Is the actual page method not found?

Comment: FireFox with firebug or Fiddler may give you some additional visibility into the problem.  Use these tools to check the request and response, and see exactly what's being sent and if it's an issue of the parameters being sent, and whether the error is a 404/500, or something else.

Comment: Ok, so I used the built in debugger in chrome and I got thisL

Comment: I got this error:                                                 POST http://localhost:1427/PortfolioWebsite/ContactForm.aspx/SendEmail 404 (Not Found) (program):5
Sys.Net.XMLHttpExecutor.executeRequest (program):5
Sys.Net._WebRequestManager.executeRequest (program):5
Sys.Net.WebRequest.invoke (program):5
Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy.invoke (program):5
Sys.Net.WebServiceProxy._invoke (program):5
PageMethods.SendEmail (program):16
PageMethods.SendEmail (program):34
EmailPageMethod (program):11
b

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving the contact form to the root directory but I still don't understand where I was supposed to specify the path. It feels like it was automatic and it just wanted to look in the root directory.

Comment: It should be automatic; the URL you specified looks in the VD root... for some reason.